# How to DRY code in iOS / Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dry

I've been programming on iOS for a few months and I think I haven't quite grasped all the concepts of Objective-C yet. Hence, I shudder every time I have to copy code between Objective-C Classes and between Projects, simply because I currently don't know better.

Just 2 examples:

1. For some of my UITextField's I require to show a pickerview instead of the standard keyboard. So I made myself a function makePicker that initializes a pickerview with a button, etc. If I have another textfield in another class I would need to copy that function over, as I couldn't find a way to share functions like these accross classes in a clean way. What would be a clean approach to this issue?
2. A lot of my classes need to read&write JSON to a http url, which means I have to decode and encode data as well as implement everything of NSURLConnectionDelegate. I would sincerly love to have a component that handles all these callbacks for me, instead of having them spread all over the place.

Thank you in advance for your inputs!

Answer (score 1):

1. Make your own subclass of `UITextField`, with custom initialization
2. [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or - if you feel adventurous - [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a class. If you don't need ivars make the methods class methods. If you do make it a subclass, in this case a subclass of `UITextField`.
2. The point of a delegate is that it can be a different class. Create a delegate class and possibly sub-classes for the delegate.

Comment: @2. So I would have something like a HTTPJSON object that implemenents the delegate methods with a few public methods to read and write?

Answer (score 1):

1/ I think your request is more POO than just iOS or Objective-C... If you need an object with more function than what the original have, just create a new class inherited from the original and add your function. Now use this new class and you'll have access to the function. Of course with Objective-c you also have the option of category if you don't need your own data to be saved in the object.

PickerTextField.h

```
@interface PickerTextField : UITextField 
@end
```

PickerTextField.m

```
@implementation PickerTextField

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
  self.inputView = YOUR-PICKER;  //YOUR-PICKER have to be create first !!!
  return [super becomeFirstResponder];
}

- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder {
    self.inputView = nil;
    return [super resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

2/ May be you need to implement the SINGLETON protocol for this, isn't it ?

Comment: What would the *SIGNLETON protocol* be?

Comment: Oups SINGLETON is better ;-D Thanks. Your solution (AFNetworking) look better, but I've not saw you had answer before me.

Comment: Typo apart, what exactly do you mean by singleton protocol?

Comment: Just a design pattern (  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern ). useful when you want a sharedInstance, with (most of the time) feed-back via notifications. You know this, isn't it ?

Comment: While I personally do not subscribe that "a kitten dies every time a singleton is used" they should be used sparingly and only when the design has been well thought out and alternatives explored.

Comment: @ArmanDOHM I do, but it's rather vague. It's like saying: "You can use methods!". Without further explanations it's kind of pointless.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, you can take advantage of `SBJson` framework which can be downloaded from following URL :

`https://github.com/stig/json-framework/downloads`

Hope it help you ;)

Comment: What do you mean by "what JSON is" ? It's an object notation : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: Or just use the Apple supplied class: `NSJSONSerialization`.

Answer (score 0):

Q1.

Way1: There are two properties `inputView` and `inputAccessoryView` in UITextField, so create your own class of InputView, something like `DatePickerInputView`, bind with the textField, change the TextField.text when the picker pick a date.

Way2: Make your own subclass of UITextField, write the code in it.

Way3: Wirte a Utils static methods, take the textField as the parameters, so you can share  your code.

Q2.

There are so many network-libraries do the stuff as your asking, like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), check out the source code, if you want to figure out how it happened.

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is no longer being developed, don't use it for new projects. From the web site: "Please note that I am no longer working on this library - you may want to consider using something else for new projects. :)" Last updated: 15th May 2011 (v1.8.1)